# Problemas al instalar linux en ordenador con Windows 10

Tags: linux, boot, grub, grub2

Este es mi problema:

Tengo un ordenador portátil con estas características:

> Lenovo ideapad 320
>
> CPU: Dual Core Intel Celeron N3350
>
> RAM: 4 Gb Disco
>
> duro SSD SATA 400 Gb

Este ordenador tiene Windows 10 instalado, y quería instalar Linux. Me he decantado, tras probar varias distros ligeras y probado las versiones *live* por [Lithium](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/), basada en Debian.

Antes de hacerlo, el disco duro contaba con (creo) tres prticiones. Una para Windows, otra para recuperación, y otra para algo de Lenovo. Antes de empezar con la instalación, reparticioné el SDD desde este mismo Lithium en modo *live*,  sacando unas particiones `/dev/sda6`, para montar `/`, `dev/sda7`, para montar `/home` y `dev/sda8` para intercambio.

Al intentar instalarlo en el disco duro obtengo siempre error en el momento de instalar GRUB. Tras varios intentos fallidos, se me ocurre usar desde Windows la aplicación [Grub2Win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/), obteniendo un menu de arranque, al que le añado una entrada nueva para linux y le pongo la partición `/dev/sda6` (donde tengo montado `/`). Sin embargo, cuando intento entrar a linux desde este menú creado por Grub2Win, me da error y en linux me aparece el prompt [(initramfs)](https://www.google.com/search?q=initramfs%20ubuntu%20stack%20overflow&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=AOaemvKehGAHJC9jtn4cGI202pCNQFDUWw%3A1641147433260&ei=KezRYcGcD6z87_UPqK27sAY&oq=initramfs%20%3A%20stac&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIGCAAQFhAeMggIABAWEAoQHjoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoECAAQQzoFCAAQgAQ6BQgAEMsBSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUL0FWMsRYJ4jaAFwAngAgAF8iAH0BZIBAzEuNpgBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)

Desde linux en modo live y ejecutando `GParted`, esta es la situación actual del disco duro:

```
Partition|Name                        |File System|Label     |Size      |Flags
/dev/sda1|EFI system partition        |fat32      |SYSTEM_DRV|260 MiB   |boot,esp
/dev/sda2|Microsoft reserved partition|unknow     |   ---    |16MiB     |msftres
/dev/sda3|Basic data partition        |ntfs       |Windows   |263.73 GiB|msftdata
/dev/sda4|Basic data partition        |ntfs       |LENOVO    |263.73 GiB|msftdata
/dev/sda5|Basic data partition        |ntfs       |WINRE_DRV |263.73 GiB|hidden, diag
/dev/sda6|                            |ext4       |          |46.57 GiB |boot,esp
/dev/sda7|                            |ext4       |          |111.76 GiB|
/dev/sda8|                            |linux-swap |          |17.46 GiB |
```

Por otro lado, desde la BIOS tengo esto en el arranque:

```
Grub2Win EFI - 64 Bit (WDC WD5000LPCX -24VHATO)
Windows Boot Manager (WDC WD5000LPCX -24VHATO)
```

No tengo ni idea de qué puedo hacer. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿has mirado `boot-repair`?  Hace tiempo que no lo hago pero creo que fue lo que usé para instalar un dual boot en unos portátiles que aun funcionan asi: https://slimbook.es/tutoriales/linux/164-3-maneras-de-como-reinstalar-o-reparar-grub-boot-repair-archlinux-o-antergos (eran ubuntu, ojo con eso)

Comment: Hola @masterguru. Parece que ya no existe este paquete. Voy a ver si el primero de los métodos que sale en el enlace que propones me funciona. Gracias!